# Hermitian locally symmetric space with nonnegative bisectional curvature

Tags: complex-manifolds, symmetric-spaces, hermitian-manifolds

Let $(M,g)$ be an Hermitian locally symmetric space with nonnegative bisectional curvature. Suppose the fundamental group of $M$ is finite, can we prove that $M$ is simply-connected?